# Could $\int{dx\over{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$ have two solitions?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

To solve $\int{dx\over{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$ you can do a substitution $u=sin(\theta)$ the result will be $\int{d\theta\over{sin(\theta)}} = ln(\mid csc(\theta)-cot(\theta)\mid)$ back substitution to $x$ will be equal $\ln{\mid{ 1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\over{x}}\mid{}}$.

But if you make the substitution $u=cos(\theta)$ the integral will be $-\int{d\theta\over{cos(\theta)}} = -ln(\mid sec(\theta)+tg(\theta)\mid)$ and the result will be  $\ln{\mid{ x\over{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\mid{}}$.

What is the right way to solve it?

Comment: $\ln\left|\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\cdot \dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right| = \cdots$

Comment: They are both equivalent expressions.

Comment: Try subbing in some limits and see what each gets you, noticing that $\ln\left|\frac ab\right|=\ln\left|\frac ba\right|$ and noting the integration constant

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $\log\left|\dfrac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|$ is $\color{red}{-}\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. So the two correct answers to the integral are actually
$$
\log\left|\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right| \; \text{and} \, \log\left|\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right| \, ,
$$
ignoring any constants of integration for now. These two expressions are the same—try rationalising the denominator of the second to see this.